# Position of place

Tags: questions

> 1. When you see a harming Chemical throwing at work place immediately inform us.
> 2. When you see a harming Chemical at work place throwing immediately inform us.

Which sentence is correct in term of placement of "at work place"?

"At work place" it should be after throwing as sentence no.1 or before of it.

Comment: By "harming Chemical throwing" do you mean someone is throwing a harmful chemical at people/objects? Or do you mean they are throwing the harmful chemical in the bin/trash?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are pretty broken, in my opinion, and neither is correct. I'm assuming that by "throw" you mean "throw away".

The correct sentence is:

> When you see a harmful chemical being thrown away in the work place, inform us immediately.

Furthermore, chemicals are hard to literally *throw away* (like you would a crisp packet). Even better is:

> When you see a harmful chemical being **disposed of** in the work place, inform us immediately.